# Why can't I answer calls through a Bluetooth device after connecting it to an iOS or Android device?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, agora.io, agora-implementation

After connecting a Bluetooth device to an iOS or Android device, I am facing the following issues:

- Fail to answer Agora video/audio calls through a bluetooth headset
- Cannot record and play audio through a Bluetooth speaker

Answer (score 0):

For your Android device check the following:

1. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` make sure you have added Bluetooth permissions

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <!-- Add the following permission on devices running Android 12.0 or later -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"  />
```

2. Check if the Bluetooth device supports SCO. If not, switch to a SCO-capable Bluetooth device.
3. Call the Android native API AudioManmager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall method to check if the device supports the use of SCO for off-call use cases. If the device does not support the feature, the user can only answer the call using the system default audio route.

For your iOS device, depending on which type of call you have an issue with, choose one of the following solutions to set the audio routes:

- Phone Call

1. Before answering a phone call, change the audio route setting in Settings: swipe down to reveal the search field, search "Call Audio Routing", and change the audio route to Bluetooth Headset. All incoming calls will be answered through the Bluetooth device even if you press the answer button on the iPhone.
2. During a phone call, you can switch between the Bluetooth Headset, Handset, or Speaker options in the call interface.
3. If you connect an iOS device to a Bluetooth speaker and answer calls in an app, ensure that the app uses the CallKit, otherwise, the above settings do not work.

- VoIP Call

1. Before making a VoIP call, you need to switch to the Bluetooth Headset mode in the Control Center. Apps can call the iOS native API `setPreferredInput` method to change the audio route.
2. When a VoIP call through the Bluetooth device is interrupted by a phone call, tap the answer button on the Bluetooth device to answer the phone call, after which you can continue the VoIP call through the Bluetooth device once the phone call ends.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same. It seems that after joining an Agora room (`onJoinChannelSuccess`) AgoraSDK triggers SCO connection to stop (I receive `AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED` in my `BroadcastReceiver`).

So you have to manually start again Bluetooth SCO after joining a room. Not sure why Agora does this, or how can this be disabled.